# how to use fixtures in other class metohds- pytest

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

Use case- I have a lot of directories that use the same tests methods in pytest and I want to centralize it in one base class and the other classes will import this base class/inherit it in order to use the common tests methods.

my issue is with the fixture.
since for each class the object that is created in the fixture is different I would like to create one dynamic fixture in the base class that will be able to get from the subclasses the object and create a fixture according to this given object.

to be more specific lets look on example that describes my case (this is what I have now):

```python
# test_connection_foo.py
from tests.base_connection_class import ConBaseTest
import FooCon

connection_obj=ConBaseTest()

@pytest.fixture()
def connection_str():
    con = FooCon()
    return con

def test_it(connection_str):
    connection_obj.connection_string(connection_str)


# tests.base_connection_class.py --> aka "base class"

import pytest
class ConBaseTest():
        
    def test_connection_string(self, connection_str):

        my_con = connection_str._check_con('foo')
        assert my_con is not None
        assert type(my_con) is str
```

in this current situation I will need to create for each subclass this fixture method. I would like to send the  FooCon() object as parameter to one dynamic fixture decorator that will create the fixture according the object.

I am open to hear for other solutions to create a base class with general tests methods that other classes can use his methods with fixture.

Comment: Can you be more specific/clear about exactly what is going wrong? If you’re getting an error, make sure to include the full traceback. If the behavior is not what you expect describe what you do expect and what you’ve tried to do to achieve this. Have you tried using session-scoped fixtures?

Answer (score 0):

To use a fixture, the test needs to be discoverable by pytest, and then simply including it as a function/method arg will work. If defining fixtures for multiple files, place them in conftest.py.

Your test class is not discoverable because it does not start with `Test`. So the full test setup should be:

in `tests/conftest.py`:

```py
@pytest.fixture()
def connection_str():
    con = FooCon()  # define/import
    return con
```

in `tests/base_connection_class.py`:

```py
class TestConBase():

    # This will be tested automatically with the fixture    
    def test_connection_string(self, connection_str):
        my_con = connection_str._check_con('foo')
        assert my_con is not None
        assert type(my_con) is str
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but its not answering my case, I am creating a base class for various other tests files to use it. imagine it as a parent class that can not located in each of the "son's" folders because its loosing the purpose.
I need a solution where the base class is in other folder and each tests files from other directory can just import it and use the general tests of the parent class.
the fixture will defined in each of the "son's" classes and will be sent as an argument to the functions of the parent class. the problem is that its taken as function and not as object

Comment: Can you update your question to clarify your actual needs through an example? I’m having a hard time following the parent/son metaphor in terms of how it translates into an actual implementation.

Comment: of course. I am updating it now.